# unable to rename series in a chart

Tags: excel, vba

first time asking a question here so please bear with me if I commit any rookie mistakes. also rather new to VBA so the code is recorded then edited, rather than coded from scratch.

i have a few issues.

firstly, the table "Ourtable" can't be deleted in the second line of code.

secondly, i can't change the series name in the fourth block of code. i think i may have unintentionally violated some VBA best practice or rule here, would you guys kindly enlighten me on my mistake here? appreciate it very much.

```
' first delete the table and charts if it is already existing
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("YTD Analysis").TableObjects("Ourtable").Delete
Sheets("YTD Analysis").ChartObjects("Missedout").Delete

' Format as table
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$N$120:$T$131"), , xlYes).Name = _
"Ourtable"
Range("Ourtable[#All]").Select
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Ourtable").TableStyle = ""

' Adding chart
Range("N121:S130").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(216, xlColumnClustered).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("WeeklyUpdate!$N$121:$S$130")
ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Missedout"

' Running into issues here, can't rename the series name!
' Series labels
With Sheets("YTD Analysis").ChartObjects("Missedout")
    .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=YTD Analysis!$O$120"
    .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=YTD Analysis!$P$120"
    .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=YTD Analysis!$Q$120"
    .SeriesCollection(4).Name = "=YTD Analysis!$R$120"
    .SeriesCollection(5).Name = "=YTD Analysis!$S$120"
End With
```

Comment: Why resume next ? - No error is reported. Change that to `Goto 0` so you can give us the error message. Or use `Debug.Print Err.Description` and update your question with errors.

Answer (score 0):

`SeriesCollection` name should be a string. It can be written directly or like a formula (to be dinamic), but if the involved sheet name contains spaces, you need to place its name between quotes:

1. `.SeriesCollection(1).Name = Worksheet("YTD Analysis).Range("$O$120").value`
2. `.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='YTD Analysis'!$O$120"`